# How to get JSON after post form?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp mvc5 project.

I have this view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", @class = "btn btn-featured btn-white" }))
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myForm').submit()">
                                <span class="hidden">@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item))</span>
                                <span>@item.Name</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

as ypu can see I have this row in view above:
    @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item))

And here is action method:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(FormCollection objViewDataModel )
    {
        //some logic  
        return View(userGroup);
    }
```

when I click on anchor tag on the view the action methos About is fired in controller, I need to access 
to hidden span control but I dont see it in my  objViewDataModel.

Any idea what I do wrong and how to access JSON inside hidden span control?

Comment: You need an `<input>` to post a value - but what you are doing will not work anyway (using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item))` makes no sense) - and what is the point of sending back the whole model unchanged. You just send back the ID of the item

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for post why it will not work?

Comment: Because you are sending back a `string` - a serialized representation of your model) and you would need to deserialize it back again. (you typically use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item))` to convert you model to a javascript object for use in a script) - but then its in a loop and your are sending back a `string` for each item in the collection, but in the post method you have no idea which one was associated with the link you clicked so its all rather pointless - you just wasted a whole lot of resources sending the data to the browser and then all back again unchanged

Comment: Its not clear why you want to make a POST instead of a GET, but you would do `foreach (var item in Model) { @using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", new id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { ... }) { <input type="submit" ... /> }` and then change the POST method to `public ActionResult About(int id)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  thanks for comment, I tried your example above:

                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { class = "btn btn-featured btn-white" }))
                    {
                        <input type="submit" value="item.Name" />
                    }
                }
 
But it not works the controller dosen't hits and no post occures

Comment: Of course it works - if its not working for you then you have other code causing the problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please make a post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180736/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be posted in a form, it should be in an input element, not a span.

So change `<span class="hidden"` to `<input type="hidden"` and give it a name.

Comment: Thanks for post can I pass only value of hidden input?